# test openssl on android

Tags: android, testing, openssl

I am trying to run openssl on android. I have observed a openssl library in android/external/openssl

its version on command prompt I got is

1.0.1j 15 Oct 2014

I build it using 
mmm -B external/openssl

I got a binary openssl and libssl.so and libcrypto.so in system/bin and system/lib respectively.

The problem is I am a newbie in this openssl and security area, so I don't know if I am doing it correctly.
I want to test AES, RC4, DES3 etc algorithms, do I have to make a test app for these or, there is built in test apps to test openssl?

P.S

Also I came to blogs which installs openssl in some other way in android, some blogs say to use BoringSSL as openssl is not supported by android.
Is there any straightforward lead to understand the flow?

Comment: Also see [OpenSSL and Android](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Android) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Comment: i can run this version of openssl on my device's command prompt. Is 'speed' command enough to benchmark it. Can I use this openssl for my android, because somewhere I came to know about that openssl is not supported. Then why it is in android source and seems like working?